# json_encode generates a very long string when I encode my table. So far my app works but will the string be too long eventually?

Tags: json, google-maps, laravel-8

The string is over 612,000 characters long. I'm using a Laravel framework to generate markers on a google map so they all have to be loaded. json_encode is a very convenient way to do it but the string is ridiculously long.

Answer (score 0):

Within a Laravel framework, instead of using json_encode I used ajax to retrieve the data so that it didn't get exposed to the browser.

blade file snippit:

```
        function initMap() {
        // Ajax call to load entire database to a Jquery array
        AjaxGet = function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr('content')
                }
            });
            var result = $.ajax({
                url: "{{url('/ajaxgetter')}}",
                method: 'post',
                async: false, //obsolete flag, but necessary so that the array does not try to set before data is retrieved
                success: function (result) {}
            }).responseText;
            return result;
        }
```

Controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    public function index () {return View('ajax');}
    public function ajaxgetter() {
        return response()->json(DB::select('select * from workorders'), 200);
    }
}
```